# How to find the smallest distance between two numbers next to each others in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a sorted array. Let's say it is `int [] numArr=new int[]{6, 9, 10, 27};`

The smallest distance is between the 9 and the 10, and it is 1. The program should print this 1.

*I am not expecting code, but I hope someone can give me an idea of how to proceed.*

Comment: loop on the array, check `item[n] - item[n+1]`, assuming a sorted ascending array, and store the smallest of the results.

Comment: `item[n] - item[n+1]` will give you negative numbers...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int smallest = 100000   

 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

    if(array[i+1]-array[i]<smallest)
     {
       smallest = array[i+1]-array[i];
     }

System.out.println(smallest);
```

Comment: What about if the smallest is 100001?

Comment: should probably stop at array.length-1 to keep from going out of bounds.

Comment: I accepted your answer not because it worked 100%, rather you helped me to clear the concept. However array.length reaches out of the array, thus, I modified it to array.length-1. And I defined the smallest integer to Integer.MAX_value.  Thanks for helping me, xoxo.

Comment: @StevenAkaTaz Its better you do the corrections in the answer as told by Simon in the comments

Answer (score 2):

Declare a variable to hold the current minimum distance.  It can be initialized to a really large number  `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so that the first distance calculated becomes the initial minimum distance.

Use a `for` loop to loop over the values.  You'll be accessing the element at the current index and the next index, so stop your `for` loop early to prevent an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

In the `for` loop, calculate the difference.  If the difference is less than the current minimum, then update the current minimum to the current difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int findSmallestDistance(final int[] pArray) {
    int lMinimumDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 1; i < pArray.length; i++) {
        int lDifference = pArray[i] - pArray[i - 1];
        if(lDifference < lMinimumDistance) {
            lMinimumDistance = lDifference;
        }
    }
    return lMinimumDistance;
}
```

Comment: Check out the selected, erroneous, answer. 
Thanks for the unnecessary downvote.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** create a variable to save the actual smallest distance

**Step 2:** iterate through your array

**Step 3:** compare your actual number with the previous on your array (if this is the first element jump this step) and if it's smaller than your smallest save the result

**Step 4:** if the array has more elements, get the next one, else print your result

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode:

Be smallest = a number surely greater than the one you're looking for

For each element i in array except the first

```
Be n = array[i] - array[i-1]

If n < smallest then

    smallest = n

End If
```

End For

Answer (score 0):

```
int numArr[] = {6, 9, 10, 27};
    for(int i=0;i<numArr.length-1;i++){
        if(numArr[i+1]-numArr[i]>0){
            System.out.println("distance between " +numArr[i]+ " and "+numArr[i+1]+ " is: "+ (numArr[i+1]-numArr[i]));
        }
    }
```